# Insert array into category in highchart stacked column

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is a sample of stacked column chart using highchart library. The part that I stucked was that I unable to insert an array containing string into categories.

```
var name = ['James', 'Jessie', 'Meouth', 'Giovani', 'Ash'];
........
      categories : name
```

When I try to do this, the words that came out is the first alphabet of the string.

[image]

The result that I want to appear is this.

[image]

Would really appreciate any helps! thanks!

Comment: Add the code where you are pushing values in categories

Comment: Which type of array data you want to put in `categories`?